# What's the difference between a while loop in one or two statements?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I am confused understanding the difference between these two loops and their results :

State 1:

```
    int n = 10;
    while (n>0) {
        cout << n << ", " << --n;
    }
```

---

State 2 :

```
    int n = 10;
    while (n>0) {
        cout << n << ", ";
        --n;
    }
```

I do not understand why should the result differentiate?

State 1 shows : 10, 99, 88, 77, 66, 55, 44, 33, 22, 11, 0

while

State 2 shows : 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,

what is happening? and what makes this difference?

Comment: first snippet prints `n` twice...

Comment: `cout << n << ", " << --n;` this displays 3 things, `n`, `", "` and `--n`. In the second loop, `cout << n << ", "; --n;` This displays 2 things, `n` and `", "`. And then, it decrements n `--n`

Comment: In your first example, change `cout << n << ", " << --n;` to `cout << n << ", " << --n << "\n";` and you should see things more clearly.

Comment: pre-C++17, you might even have stranger result with undetermined evaluation order.

Comment: @PaulSanders Thank you! yes, it makes everything clear dude! ;-)

Comment: @anatolyg Being answered in comments is not the question fault and hence no reason for close-voting. Nudging the commenters to create an answer is appropriate. Or creating one yourself ...

Comment: @Cid Thanks! you mentioned an important point, now I understand that `cout` does not involve `--n` in the second example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference in the values, just in the number of times they are occurring because of being printed a different number of times.

The first one outputs, with "()" added for clarity:

`(10, 9)(9, 8)(8, 7)(7, 6)(6, 5)(5, 4)(4, 3)(3, 2)(2, 1)(1, 0)`

Note that there are pairs of numbers without a "," in between, created by the start and the end of the ouput.

The second one outputs:

`(10, )(9, )(8, )(7, )(6, )(5, )(4, )(3, )(2, )(1,)`

Note that I do not discuss in this question the topic of unreliable order of evaluation caused by using `++` on a value and outputting it in the same statement. This is only about the difference of behaviour you observe in your environment.